# Recognize routes in rails console Session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Say I have a router helper that I want more info on, like blogs_path, how do I find out the map statements behind that in console.

I tried generate and recognize and I got unrecognized method error, even after I did require 'config/routes.rb'

Answer (score 103, accepted):

There is a good summary with examples at [Zobie's Blog](http://blog.zobie.com/2008/11/testing-routes-in-rails/) showing how to manually check URL-to-controller/action mapping and the converse. For example, start with

```
 r = Rails.application.routes
```

to access the routes object (Zobie's page, a couple years old, says to use `ActionController::Routing::Routes`, but that's now deprecated in favor of `Rails.application.routes`). You can then check the routing based on a URL:

```
 >> r.recognize_path "/station/index/42.html"
 => {:controller=>"station", :action=>"index", :format=>"html", :id=>"42"}
```

and see what URL is generated for a given controller/action/parameters combination:

```
 >> r.generate :controller => :station, :action=> :index, :id=>42
 => /station/index/42
```

Thanks, Zobie!

Comment: Nice. Is there a way you can test named routes like `root_path` with this method?

Comment: @brittohalloran `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.my_path_helper`

Comment: This is awesome, this trick helped me solve another problem, thanks alot :)

Comment: The method recognize_path accepts a hash of options, so to check against a specific HTTP verb you can use: `r.recognize_path "/station/submit", method: "POST"`

Answer (score 58):

In the console of a Rails 3.2 app:

```ruby
# include routing and URL helpers
include ActionDispatch::Routing
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

# use routes normally
users_path #=> "/users"
```

Comment: Doesn't seem like the `include ActionDispatch::Routing` is needed.

Comment: This is a great candidate for inclusion in one's `.pryrc` or `.irbrc` file

Answer (score 33):

Basically(if I understood your question right) it boils down to including the UrlWriter Module:

```
   include ActionController::UrlWriter
   root_path
   => "/"
```

Or you can prepend app to the calls in the console e.g.:

```
   ruby-1.9.2-p136 :002 > app.root_path
   => "/"
```

(This is all Rails v. 3.0.3)

Comment: include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers is Rails 3 way to do it.

Comment: for some routes you need to set a default host for them to work
e.g. 

default_url_options[:host] = 'foo'

Answer (score 4):

running the routes command from your project directory will display your routing:

```
rake routes
```

is this what you had in mind?

Comment: rake routes will give all routes. I'm trying for something more specific like .generate and .recognize methods, except for helpers. So if I enter in blogs_path, I should get :action => index, :controller => :blog

Answer (score 3):

If you are seeing errors like

```
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches
```

Where it should be working, you may be using a rails gem or engine that does something like Spree does where it prepends routes, you may need to do something else to view routes in console.

In spree's case, this is in the routes file

```
Spree::Core::Engine.routes.prepend do
  ...
end
```

And to work like @mike-blythe suggests, you would then do this before `generate` or `recognize_path`.

```
r = Spree::Core::Engine.routes
```