# Rails 3: I want to list all paths defined in my rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I want to list all defined helper path functions (that are created from routes) in my rails 3 application, if that is possible.

Thanks,

Comment: open your console and type rake routes

Answer (score 266, accepted):

**new solution**

```
rails routes
```

**deprecated**

```
rake routes
```

or

```
bundle exec rake routes
```

Comment: Furthermore, if you want to check whether a given path is *recognized* by your app's router, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4513327).

Comment: In a specific context, I had to use `RAILS_ENV=dev  /opt/rbenv/shims/bundle rake routes` to make this work.

Comment: `rake routes` is deprecated; use `rails routes` instead: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/33660

Answer (score 101):

### Update

I later found that, there is an official way to see all the routes, by going to http://localhost:3000/rails/info/routes. Official docs: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#listing-existing-routes

---

Though, it may be late, But I love the error page which displays all the routes. I usually try to go at `/routes` (or some bogus) path directly from the browser. Rails server automatically gives me a routing error page as well as all the routes and paths defined. That was very helpful :)

So, Just go to http://localhost:3000/routes [image]

Comment: To state the obvious, this only works in development environment.

Comment: This is bundled into Rails 4, but the question asks about Rails 3.  You'll need to install the Sextant gem to use this in 3.

Answer (score 37):

One more solution is

```
Rails.application.routes.routes
```

http://hackingoff.com/blog/generate-rails-sitemap-from-routes/

Comment: `Rails.application.routes.routes.map { |r| {alias: r.name, path: r.path.spec.to_s, controller: r.defaults[:controller], action: r.defaults[:action]}}`

Comment: ```Rails.application.routes.routes.map(&:name).compact``` for just the named routes

Answer (score 13):

```
rails routes | grep <specific resource name>
```

displays resource specific routes, if it is a pretty long list of routes.

Comment: You can pass `--grep` directly to `rails routes` like: `rails routes --grep "^/password"`

Answer (score 10):

Trying `http://0.0.0.0:3000/routes` on a Rails 5 API app (i.e.: JSON-only oriented) will (as of Rails beta 3) return

```
{"status":404,"error":"Not Found","exception":"#> 
<ActionController::RoutingError:...
```

However, `http://0.0.0.0:3000/rails/info/routes` will render a nice, simple HTML page with routes.

Answer (score 7):

### CLI

*updated for version 6*

To [list all existing routes](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#listing-existing-routes) you'll want to run the command:

```sh
bundle exec rails routes
```

[bundle exec](https://bundler.io/v2.2/man/bundle-exec.1.html) will

> Execute a command in the context of the bundle

and [rails routes](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#bin-rails-routes) will

> list all of your defined routes

### Example

If you have your [resource](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) route declared like so:

```
resource :credential, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
```

Then it's helpful to [pipe](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Pipelines) the output so you can [grep](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html) for your specific resource.

For example:
[image: bundle exec rails routes grep example]