# Rails redirect 301

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect

I have some touble with redirect 301 in my new app. I have to redirect some old urls into the new one.
I entred in my routes file this

```
match "/traslochi_puglia/index.htm", :to => redirect("/preventivo/90-traslochi-in-puglia")
```

and it works fine, but I can't understand why this

```
match "/trasloco_casa_abitazione.htm", :to => redirect("/3-trasloco-casa")
```

does not work. All the old urls with this pattern "/some_path/page.htm" works fine but not "page.htm". Any hint?
Thanks

Comment: I'm a dumb, I put this match '/:id' => "frontends#show", :as => :frontend before all the redirects

Answer (score 0):

If you want us to troubleshoot the specific issue you've outlined in your question, we need to see your entire `routes.rb` file. Without this information, my first guess is this:

The typical route pattern is `/controller/action` or `/controller/:id/action` or some combination thereof. With the pattern you've shown above, and assuming you have no named routes in your `routes.rb` file, then the route you've provided would point to a controller, but not an action. Therefore your app **wouldn't know what action to execute**, unless you've specifically created a route called `/3-trasloco-casa` which looks to me more like a URL to a specific resource, than an action on a controller.

Getting to the source of routing issues can most easily be done with a combination of running `rake routes` at the command line (which shows you the list of route patterns your app will recognize), and then going further by troubleshooting with route recognition, as outlined in this answer to this question:

[Recognize routes in rails console Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778074/recognize-routes-in-rails-console-session)