# Rails Upgrade To 3.2 ActionNotFound Strange Routing Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rather bizarre error happening on upgrading from Rails 3.1.12 to 3.2.17.

Basically, I can load a page once, but as soon as I hit refresh, I get a

```
AbstractController::ActionNotFound
```

I'll say that again incase you missed it. I CAN load the page, ONCE.  So I know the routes are fine, but if I refresh the exact same page, I get this action not found.

This happens on every single page.  I can view it once, but on refresh I can't view it again.

Ways to fix it, are to either bounce the rails server or make a change to the routes file and save it.

The routes file is way to big to post, so i'll just use a single page for an example here.
The page is found at */dashboard*

The route is:

```
match '/dashboard', :to => 'pages#dashboard'
```

I hit that page, it loads fine, I hit it again, it fails with

```
AbstractController::ActionNotFound at /dashboard
The action 'dashboard_pages' could not be found for PagesController
```

The action is called "dashboard" on the pages controller.

Iv been googling this for a while now, and its the whole "1 view" thing that has be baffled. I cant find anyone else who has this problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Heres the stack trace:

```
    AbstractController::ActionNotFound - The action 'dashboard_pages' could not be found for PagesController:
      actionpack (3.2.17) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:116:in `process'
      actionpack (3.2.17) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
      actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
      actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
      actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
      actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
      actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
      journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
      journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
      actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:608:in `call'
      meta_request (0.2.8) lib/meta_request/middlewares/app_request_handler.rb:13:in `call'
      rack-contrib (1.1.0) lib/rack/contrib/response_headers.rb:17:in `call'
      meta_request (0.2.8) lib/meta_request/middlewares/headers.rb:16:in `call'
      meta_request (0.2.8) lib/meta_request/middlewares/meta_request_handler.rb:13:in `call'
      newrelic_rpm (3.7.3.204) lib/new_relic/rack/error_collector.rb:55:in `call'
      newrelic_rpm (3.7.3.204) lib/new_relic/rack/agent_hooks.rb:32:in `call'
      newrelic_rpm (3.7.3.204) lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:27:in `call'
      newrelic_rpm (3.7.3.204) lib/new_relic/rack/developer_mode.rb:45:in `call'
      http_accept_language (2.0.1) lib/http_accept_language/middleware.rb:13:in `call'
      warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
      warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
      actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
      rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
      rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
      actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
      actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
      actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
      rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
      rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
      actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
      activerecord (3.2.17) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
      activerecord (3.2.17) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
      actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
      activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__3098765915505928900__call__1549657330245414969__callbacks'
      activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
      activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
      activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
      actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
      actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
      actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
      better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
      better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
      better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:56:in `call'
      actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
      actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
      railties (3.2.17) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
      railties (3.2.17) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
      activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
      railties (3.2.17) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
      actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
      rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
      rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
      activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
      rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
      actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call'
       () usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@secure/bundler/gems/raven-ruby-e6d646402dc7/lib/raven/rack.rb:47:in `call'
      railties (3.2.17) lib/rails/engine.rb:484:in `call'
      railties (3.2.17) lib/rails/application.rb:231:in `call'
      rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
      railties (3.2.17) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
      rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
      /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
      /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
      /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Could you have a go at the new routing-style by upgrading that to: `get 'dashboard', to: 'pages#dashboard'` (also look at the routing rails guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html )

Comment: Hi Taryn,  its the same problem.  It will work once, but then not again.

Comment: ok. Well, it was worth testing :) So now - what's in your pages_controller and he view for the dashboard? is there somewhere that you refer to the dashboard path? (I'm guessing not because it's for all views... but it might help). Also - do you have a full stacktrace?

Comment: Ill update the post with the stack trace

Comment: Also its worth mentioning that when this error occurs, it has not even hit my code yet.  I can put a break point on the first line of code in my application controller and it wont hit it. (you can see this from the stack trace)   So, code in my views, or controllers are not the problem it would seem.

Comment: Ok, so I'd look into how routing differs for the two versions of rails you're using. From what I recall of upgrades - the very first line of code was different... but it's been a while.

Comment: Thanks Taryn, I just tried disabling all but a few routes, also updating them to use the 'get' syntax, but i'm still getting the same thing.   Im using better errors and i was able to use the console to prove that the route still matches even when the error occurs using this technique: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4513327/573616.   Its like it completely loses track of the controller after one view.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.

There was a piece of code that was printing  action_name << controller_name in the view.  In Rails 3.1 , this just concatenated the strings and printed it.  In 3.2 is alters the request parameters.